# Flutter Bluetooth Serial Android embedded

Tags: android, flutter, bluetooth

I'm working with flutter and I'm getting this error while I was trying to add lutter_bluetooth_serial to the pubspec.yaml. This is the error that I get.-->"The plugin flutter_bluetooth_serial uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding. To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs. If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: [https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration."](https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.%22) ---->I don't know how to solve this issue Can you help??? I also changed to buildgradle->defaultConfig{
minSdkVersion 19 };

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

flutter_blue, the author of package should update the package,to match the flutter version.
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue

There is nothing you can do. Either use an other package or ask the package developer to fix the problem.

you can try
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue
do your stuff, this package has function like flutter_blue.